# Inserting matched word into sqlite3 database

Tags: python, sqlite, praw

I am using PRAW and python to find names in a specific subreddit. In this case, I am looking for dota names and wanting to put them into a database. Here is my code.

```
#import praw (for the reddit api of course), time (for timer between loops), re (for the regular expression on hero names), and sqlite3 to store in your database!
import praw
import time
import re
import sqlite3

#username for reddit. This will not make an account so go on reddit and make another account and put username and password here.
username = "LewisTheRobot"
password = ""


#Enter what subreddit you want to choose
subreddit_choice = "dota2"
#credentials of your sqlite database. Download sqlite3 viewer to make one easily.
conn = sqlite3.connect('dotaheroes')
c = conn.cursor()
#user_agent tells the reddit servers what your bot does.
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent = "Count amount of times heroes are mentioned")

#lists all dota heroes in game
words_to_match = [r'\babaddon\b', r'\balchemist\b', r'\bancient apparition\b', r'\banti mage\b', r'\baxe\b', r'\bbane\b', r'\bbatrider\b', r'\bbeastmaster\b', r'\bbloodseeker\b', r'\bbounty hunter\b', r'\rbrewmaster\b', r'\bbristleback\b', r'\bbroodmother\b', r'\bcentaur warrunner\b', r'\bchaos knight\b', r'\bchen\b', r'\bclinkz\b', r'\bclockwerk\b', r'\bcrystal maiden\b', r'\bdark seer\b', r'\bdazzle\b', r'\bdeath prophet\b', r'\bdisruptor\b', r'\bdoom\b', r'\bdragon knight\b', r'\bdrow ranger\b', r'\bearthshaker\b', r'\bearth spirt\b', r'\belder titan\b', r'\bember spirit\b', r'\benchantress\b', r'\benigma\b', r'\bfaceless void\b', r'\bgyrocopter\b', r'\bhuskar\b', r'\binvoker\b', r'\bio\b', r'\bjakiro\b', r'\bjuggernaut\b', r'\bkeeper of the light\b', r'\bkunkka\b', r'\blegion commander\b', r'\bleshrac\b', r'\blich\b', r'\blifestealer\b', r'\blina\b', r'\blion\b', r'\blone druid\b', r'\bluna\b', r'\blycan\b', r'\bmagnus\b', r'\bmedusa\b', r'\bmeepo\b', r'\bmirana\b', r'\bmorphling\b', r'\bnaga siren\b', r'\bnatures prophet\b', r'\bnecrophos\b', r'\bnight stalker\b', r'\bnyx assassin\b', r'\bogre magi\b', r'\bomniknight\b', r'\boracle\b', r'\boutworld devourer\b', r'\bphantom assassin\b', r'\bphantom lancer\b', r'\bpheonix\b', r'\bpuck\b', r'\bpudge\b', r'\bpugna\b', r'\bqueen of pain\b', r'\brazor\b', r'\briki\b', r'\brubick\b', r'\bsand king\b', '\bshadow demon\b', r'\bshadow fiend\b', r'\bshadow shaman\b', r'\bsilencer\b', r'\bskywrath mage\b', r'\bslardar\b', r'\bslark\b', r'\bsniper\b', r'\bspectre\b', r'\bspirit breaker\b', r'\bstorm spirit\b', r'\bsven\b', r'\btechies\b', r'\btemplar assassin\b', r'\bterrorblade\b', r'\btidehunter\b', r'\btimbersaw\b', r'\btinker\b', r'\btiny\b', r'\btreant protector\b', r'\btroll warlord\b', r'\btusk\b', r'\bundying\b', r'\bursa\b', r'\bvengeful spirit\b', r'\bvenomancer\b', r'\bviper\b', r'\bvisage\b', r'\bwarlock\b', r'\bweaver\b', r'\bwindranger\b', r'\bwitch doctor\b', r'\bwraith king\b', r'\bzeus\b']


#Empty list to store all comments in so that the prompt can show you how many have been counted

storage = []

r.login(username, password)

def run_bot():
    subreddit = r.get_subreddit(subreddit_choice)
    print("Grabbing subreddit")
    comments = subreddit.get_comments(limit=200)
    print("Grabbing comments")
    for comment in comments:
        comment_text = comment.body.lower()
        isMatch = any(re.search(string, comment_text) for string in words_to_match)
        if comment.id not in storage and isMatch and comment.author not in storage:
            print("A hero was mentioned! Adding to database :)")
            storage.append(comment.author)
            c.execute("INSERT INTO heroes (id, hero_name) VALUES(?, ?)", (str(comment.id), str(isMatch)))
            conn.commit()

    print("There are currently " + str(len(storage)) + " people who have said a hero name.")



while True:
    run_bot()
    time.sleep(2)
```

My main problem comes from this line of code right here.

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO heroes (id, hero_name) VALUES(?, ?)", (str(comment.id), str(isMatch)))
```

I am trying to insert the hero/name that is mentioned from the list and insert it into the database without all of the other comment. Just the hero. So in short, I am looking for a way to insert the name that it matches and put it into the database instead of having the whole comment there. Thank you.

EDIT (Clarification):  My code goes through reddit comments and matches with the names that I have listed in my list: "words_to_match". Currently it just matches the comment and then runs the sql line that I have. However, it returns True instead of the Hero name that I want inserted into the database.

Comment: I personally do not understand what you are asking. If you want to insert just hero name, whatever it is, just insert it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. My code goes through reddit comments and matches with the names that I have listed in my list: "words_to_match". Currently it just matches the comment and then runs the sql line that I have. However, it returns True instead of the Hero name that I want inserted into the database. @akonsu

Comment: you need to replace your call to `any` with a custom code that stops when it sees a match, and save the word that matched (your `string`) into the DB